# How do I set different digest algorithm and signature algorithm for an idp in simplesamlphp

Tags: simplesamlphp

I am trying to set

DigestMethod Algorithm to

```
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256
```

and SignatureMethod Algorithm to

```
http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
```

I have set

```
'metadata.sign.algorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256'
```

and

```
'signature.algorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'
```

I saw from a changelog that metadata.sign.algorithm was introduced as the digest algorithm. However both digest algorithm and signature algorithm seem to be taking from the value signature.algorithm. I am using SimpleSamlP v1.18.4.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like SimpleSamlPHP does not allow this to be done. However I patched Utils.php inside SAML2 library to get this working

```
diff --git a/src/SAML2/Utils.php b/src/SAML2/Utils.php
index e894a3e..4894f84 100644
--- a/src/SAML2/Utils.php
+++ b/src/SAML2/Utils.php
@@ -339,6 +339,11 @@ class Utils
                 $type = XMLSecurityDSig::SHA1;
         }

+        // Patch to get SimpleSAMLPHP to return different
+        // algorithms for signature and digest
+        // to address Login.gov logout issue.
+        $type = XMLSecurityDSig::SHA256;
+
         $objXMLSecDSig->addReferenceList(
             [$root],
             $type,
```

I set the signature algorithm to SHA1 in the config and applied this patch via composer to have digest use the SHA256 algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The digest algorithm will be based on signature algorithm, at least this is so out of the box in simpleSAMLphp 1.18.4. If you set `signature.algorithm` to `http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256` you'll get `http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256` as the digest algorithm. This is your best option.

In more detail:

The underlying XML Digital Signature spec does not say that the digest algorithm (`DigestMethod` element) has to depend on or be derived from the signing algorithm (`SignatureMethod` element). In practice, many XML Digital Signature libraries *do* base digest algorithm on signature algorithm as the default option. Some libraries allow these defaults to be manipulated, others do not. simpleSAMLphp uses `XMLSecurityKey` from [xmlseclibs](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs) to compute signatures. Here's a constructor of XMLSecurityKey from `xmlseclibs` 3.0.4 that simpleSAMLphp 1.18.4 depends on:

```php
   case (self::RSA_SHA256):
                $this->cryptParams['library'] = 'openssl';
                $this->cryptParams['method'] = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256';
                $this->cryptParams['padding'] = OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING;
                $this->cryptParams['digest'] = 'SHA256';
                if (is_array($params) && ! empty($params['type'])) {
                    if ($params['type'] == 'public' || $params['type'] == 'private') {
                        $this->cryptParams['type'] = $params['type'];
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

As you can see, if it sees RSA-SHA256 as the signature algorithm, it sets the digest algorithm to SHA256. The digest/signature algorithms can be changed after construction but  simpleSAMLphp doesn't go that far.

SAML has a [profile](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-metadata-algsupport.html) that allows algorithms (including signature and digest) to be declared in metadata. The lower-level [saml PHP library](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/saml2) apparently [supports](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/issues/536) this profile. You could give this a shot if you're not afraid of rolling your own implementation using this library.

Answer (score 0):

I find  https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/simplesamlphp-1.18/lib/SimpleSAML/Metadata/Signer.php use `metadata.sign.algorithm` for signing metadata and `signature.algorithm` used by https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/simplesamlphp-1.18/modules/saml/lib/Message.php to sign any messages from a Service Provider (SP).

Did you set all the related configuration for `metadata.sign.algorithm` in the configuration?

```
'metadata.sign.enable' => false,
'metadata.sign.privatekey' => null,
'metadata.sign.privatekey_pass' => null,
'metadata.sign.certificate' => null,
'metadata.sign.algorithm' => null,
```

Comment: Isn't that for signing the metatdata for the metadata end point? I tried enabling 'metadata.sign.enable' => false, but that did not have an impact in the logic. I added some code in the signer.php sign method but it was not going in there for the logout process.